# Is it possible to use OpenVPN to make a local server available publicly?

Tags: openvpn, ip

Is it possible to use OpenVPN to make a local server available publicly, like ngrok or pagekite?

I've seen [portmap.io](https://portmap.io) which can make a locally running server publicly available. Meaning, I neither need to touch any network settings or have a public IP. It uses OpenVPN to achieve this.

I was wondering how they do this. I actually want to make use of OpenVPN to achieve the same thing but without portmap.